# l2tp connection in ubuntu 16.10

Tags: openvpn, vpn, l2tp

Recently I needed to use a VPN connection to surf the web. I've googled it and found some solutions about L2TP connections. I follow all the instructions that introduce but after I want to make the connection enable, my Lan card be disable and invisible, is this problem have any solution? 
I have installed StrongSwan and follow their instructions.

As my second question:

Lately I use Cisco AnyConnect and OPENVPN as virtual private network but after last update, when ever I want to enable this connection, it shows me this error: your VPN service was stop.

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) first and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.  In this case, you should ask one question, and you should show what you tried and what errors you ran into.